# Only Wi-Fi is working but not ethernet

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

Today I connected lan cable and I found that ethernet is not working (no icon also for ethernet).
Output of `ifconfig` :

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1073  bytes 115411 (115.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1073  bytes 115411 (115.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.40  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a181:9afb:22ae:b05  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b4:8c:9d:66:75:3d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 28934  bytes 25749531 (25.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15772  bytes 3193820 (3.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Ouput of `sudo lshw -c network`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc704000-fc704fff memory:fc700000-fc703fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: b4:8c:9d:66:75:3d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=5.15.0-89-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=192.168.1.40 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:ff0-fef iomemory:ff0-fef iomemory:ff0-fef irq:77 memory:ff20300000-ff203fffff memory:ff20400000-ff20403fff memory:ff20404000-ff20404fff
```

**Note :**

- I have done `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`.
- I have downloaded and install the driver from [www.realtek.com](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software)

After doing above two steps, I did restart, but ethernet is still not working but WI-FI is working.
Please help on this or I have to reinstall the **Kubuntu 22.04**

Comment: Please describe in more detail the process you used to install the driver. Also, please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8169 && sudo dmesg | grep r816` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.